# jQuery Deferred - Adding a callback to the Deferred contract

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to add another asynchronous call to the contract of an existing Deferred before its state is set to success. Rather than try and explain this in English, see the following pseudo-code:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({        
        url: someUrl,
        data: data,
        async: true,        
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            console.log('Call 1 done.')
            jqXhr.pipe(
                $.ajax({        
                    url: someUrl,
                    data: data,
                    async: true,        
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
                        console.log('Call 2 done.');
                    },       
                })
            );
        },       
    }),
    $.ajax({        
        url: someUrl,
        data: data,
        async: true,        
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            console.log('Call 3 done.');
        },       
    })
).then(function(){ console.log('All done!'); });
```

Basically, Call 2 is dependent on the results of Call 1. I want Call 1 and Call 3 to be executed in parallel. Once all 3 calls are complete, I want the All Done code to execute. My understanding is that `Deferred.pipe()` is supposed to chain another asynchronous call to the given deferred, but in practice, I always get Call 2 completing after All Done.

Does anyone know how to get jQuery's Deferred to do what I want? Hopefully the solution doesn't involve ripping the code apart into chunks any further.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: Please see my [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644372/jquery-deferred-add-callbacks-to-the-deferred-contract-at-runtime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `.pipe` on the deferred object returned by the first `$.ajax` call, not inside its success callback (this does not have any effect at all):

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({        
        // ...      
    }).pipe(function() {
        // return a deferred object from .pipe
        return $.ajax({        
            // ...      
        });
    }),
    $.ajax({        
        // ...       
    })
).done(function(){ console.log('All done!'); });
```

`.pipe` returns a new deferred object  which only gets resolved once both, the original deferred object and the returned one get resolved.

Comment: it does in 1.8+, where `.then` is now equivalent to `.pipe` itself

Comment: Oh right, I remember something like that... they should really update the docs. I guess it does not make a huge difference in this case, but it makes more sense. Thanks!

Comment: ISTR the difference is that `.pipe` returns a _new_ promise, whereas `.then` returns the original promise.

Comment: Ok, this works. Is there a way to pass the results of Call 1 into the Call 2 function without using closures or global variables?

Comment: @MgSam: Sure, the result is passed as arguments to the `.pipe` callback. I'm not sure which values are all passed for Ajax responses, so just log the arguments and see what you need.

Comment: Ok. My situation is actually more complicated than my original explanation showed. Please see the updated question.